# Mark a 3rd party dependency as deprecated in Gradle buid script

Tags: gradle

In the `build.gradle` of my project, I have a dependency added:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'some-lib'
}
```

I want to deprecate the usage of this library in the project. I.e., I want it to be there, to compile and run but just warn the user when he's using methods from this library.
I can't remove the dependency right away because I need some time to refactor already existing usages. With deprecation, I want to prevent new usages of this lib.

Is it possible to mark the dependency as deprecated in Gradle?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to mark a dependency as deprecated, but you should be able to add

```
afterEvaluate {
    if ('some-lib' in configurations.testImplementation.allDependencies.name) {
        logger.warn("**** WARNING: some-lib is deprecated and will be removed.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I'm aware of this. But I was looking for a solution that would show warnings in IDE while writing the code.